try to understand OpenSSL EVP_DigestSign functions
I am still learning to use EVP_DigestSign functions (https://docs.openssl.org/master/man3/EVP_DigestSignInit/#description). One thing I feel puzzled is that the digest type is somehow restricted to the key type.
Quote: "Not all digests can be used for all key types."
Especially for ED25519, it does not support digest. Why?
If it can only sign the whole message, then what if I precompute the digest of the message (using any digest I like), then let it sign the digest instead? Does it violate anything or introduce any vulnerability?

For Ed25519 and Ed448, the specification defines the digest, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67619, which is why there is no need to specify the digest.

looks like the document is confusing, quote "Ed25519 and Ed448  Support no digests (the digest type must be NULL)".

This refers to the API. In the API, no specification of a digest is required for Ed25519 (or Ed448) because the algorithm only allows a single digest, for Ed25519 this is SHA-512 (for Ed448 this is SHAKE-256), see this post or RFC 8032 itself. In contrast e.g. ECDSA allows different digests, which is why the digest to be used must be specified in the API.

For precomputed hashes there is EVP_PKEY_sign() For Ed25519 and precomputed hashes, see Ed25519ph.

@Topaco, Thank you for your very help comments!
